# how to wait until login is verified with selenium automation testing in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have to do frontend automation testing with selenium in C#. I have started learning and started with filling parameters in textbox and clicking login button.

But requirement is that, after clicking login button, I need to wait to check for login is success or not and only if success , need to proceed to next test.
I am using VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting reference. This is the starting method and only after successful login I need to proceed further testing methods.

I am stuck here on how to wait to verify and proceed to next method, following is my code

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void LoginWithParameters()
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TestURL"]);
        var userName = driver.FindElement(By.Id("UserName"));
        var passWord = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Password"));
        var logOn = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@value='Log On']"));
        userName.SendKeys(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"]);
        passWord.SendKeys(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"]);
        logOn.Click();


        var str = driver.PageSource;

        Assert.IsTrue(str.Contains("Login was unsuccessful"));


    }
```

Please help with this or any proper tutorials .
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably the success message is displayed in DIV or something similar. So you can use WebDriverWait.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(
By.Id("successDivId")));
// code after successful login...
```

You can also check here, a summarised sheet- https://automatetheplanet.com/selenium-webdriver-csharp-cheat-sheet/

You don't need conditional code in your tests, just create two different tests for the successful login and for the unsuccessful.

Comment: Hi Angelov, thanks for the response. actually if login is successful, page will be redirected from Login to Home page, is it possible to stop this redirection till verification is done ? and I need to add wait.Unitl after my button click?

Comment: You don't need to stop the redirection. Just add the assert .Text or something else to the success element and then add second assert that you are redirected to the correct page. This should work.

Comment: As Anton says you'd be better finding a good condition to verify that the login was successful and failing otherwise. I.e. you expect to see the home page if the login was successful so use a wait with the condition of either the URL changing (probably not the best solution) or a condition of finding an element on the home page that you'd always expect to be there and that isn't present on the login page. If that condition fails you can be fairly certain you've failed to log in.

Comment: @AntonAngelov Hi , I am  bit confused with your example, how to use two assert statements, could you give some code example please?

Comment: You can use something similar after the wait: var element = this.driver.FindElement(By.Id("successDivId"));
Assert.AreEqual<string>("Login was unsuccessful", element.Text);

Comment: @AntonAngelov : Hi, thanks, I have done it in same way and now I am able to wait till login is successful and going to next page.